# Scala method unable to infer return type

Tags: scala

I failed to understand why, if I specify return type of my function scala compiler complains. I am pretty sure that it is happening because I am using [F-bounded polymorphism](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded). Everything in on scala(2.11) shell. Here is my class definition:

```
trait Base[T <: Base[T]]

case class Derived(id: Long) extends Base[Derived]
```

This works (without explicit return type):

```
def buildThisWorks1[T<:Base[T]]() = Derived(1)
```

However this does not work:

```
def buildNotWorking[T<:Base[T]]() : T = Derived(1)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Derived
 required: T
       def buildNotWorking[T<:Base[T]]() : T = Derived(1)
```

If I typecast `Derived` class to be of type `T` it works, which is confusing me.

```
def buildThisWorks2[T<:Base[T]]() : T =  Derived(1).asInstanceOf[T]
```

Note that in second definition I make `Derived` as instance of `T` (which according to me is redundant since Derived is already a subtype of `Base` but it works).

```
def buildThisWorks2[T<:Base[T]]() : T =  Derived(1).asInstanceOf[T]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't specify the return type of this method, the compiler infers it:

```
scala> def buildThisWorks1[T <: Base[T]]() = Derived(1)
buildThisWorks1: [T <: Base[T]]()Derived
```

Here, the return type is inferred as `Derived`, and not `T`. In fact, the type parameter does absolutely nothing here, because the method will always return the `Derived` type.

---

The following cannot work, because we do not know that `T = Derived`. `T` can be any type that satisfies the constraint `T <: Derived[T]`. While it's true that there is only one type here that satisfies the condition, the compiler isn't going to assume that `T = Derived`. You could easily add `class Extra extends Base[Extra]`, which would suddenly and mysteriously cause the method to break (if it worked in the first place).

```
def buildNotWorking[T <: Base[T]]() : T = Derived(1)
```

---

The type-cast works because you are forcing the type of `Derived(1)` to be that of `T`. If `T` is actually `Derived`, then everything is okay.

```
def buildThisWorks2[T <: Base[T]]() : T =  Derived(1).asInstanceOf[T]
```

But the cast is telling the compiler to ignore any type errors, which will cause problems at runtime. If `T` is not really `Derived`, you're going to have a problem.

```
class Bad extends Base[Bad]

scala> buildThisWorks2[Bad]
java.lang.ClassCastException: Derived cannot be cast to Bad
  ... 33 elided
```

We get a `ClassCastException`, because `T` is actually my `Bad` type, and `Derived` cannot be cast to it.

---

All in all, it's unclear what you want this to do. Typically, type parameters are inferred from the parameters of a method. But here, there are no parameters to this method, so there is nothing to infer the parameter type. The compiler is okay with this, because you can still manually supply the type parameter (as I did in the example that caused the exception). The type parameter `T` cannot be inferred from the return value of the method, because that generally should depend on the caller via parameters (or be static).

Essentially, the type parameter for these methods don't serve a purpose, and are completely ignored since you're returning the same type `Derived` every time. Something that would make more sense would accept a `Base[T]` as a parameter, do something with it, and return it (maybe?).

```
def doSomething[T <: Base[T]](t: T): T = t // not very creative
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! This is a distilled version of problem so wont make much sense :) You said compiler won't automatically infer `Derived` of type `T` because return type can be any subtype of Base. I wonder why it wont infer that. Since function return types are covariant i should be able to return any subtype of `Base`. Or is this because of fn vs method issue.

Comment: Your second to last sentence about covariance isn't quite true. `Derived` and `T` both extend `Base`, but that doesn't mean you can swap one for the other. That's not an up-cast, it's a lateral comparison.

Comment: ah that's true. T is actually a subtype of `Base` so I can't just replace it with `Derived`. For my education could you point me to some documentation which explains ` Typically, type parameters are inferred from the parameters of a method.` How does that work? Does it depend from case to case?  Other than that I think your explanation is pretty solid!

Comment: what I was trying to do here is to create a Factory which would return objects of subtype depending on passed parameter. A definition like this: `def buildTest[T<:Base[T]](t: String) = t match { case "d1" => Derived(1); case "d2" => OtherDerivedClase(1)}`.  This way client code will directly get derived object and can access all methods of it. But this does not work as expected since I have to typecast return value to be able to access derived class specific methods .

Comment: That won't work. The scala compiler can't infer `T` from a `String`, nor will it inspect the method code to try to find out what `T` should be. Put it this way: the type parameters must be known *before* the method is ever executed. If we need to execute the method to determine the return type, it's too late. The best approximation that method can return is `Base[_]`, which I'm sure is not useful to you. But getting something like that to work  is really another question, entirely.

Comment: cool make sense. I will try to dig more and if unable to find a good solution will post a question on Factory pattern :D